# use factoryboy for django User with Pytest

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pytest-django, pytest-factoryboy

I am migrating the UnitTests of a Django app to py.test, but in the UnitTests they make use of factory-boy to create instances of django.contrib.auth.models.User. how can this be done with pytest-factory-boy?

Comment: I would advise against using too much of these "glue" libraries like pytest-factory-boy. In my opinion they over-complicate things and can make your code harder to reason about. You can just use the vanilla factory-boy in your test suit and add glue ad hoc.

Comment: Did you checked this [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-factoryboy/1.1.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-factoryboy/1.1.4)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a user in py.test, without to need for a factory is quite simple.
py.test already has a helper containing a builtin Django admin_user and admin_client fixture as explained [here](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#admin-client-django-test-client-logged-in-as-admin).

Here some code, for usage in your conftest.py to create a normal user:

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
@pytest.fixture
def user_client(client):
    """
    User fixture for tests with unprivileged user
    """
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='user',
        password='pass',
        first_name='Normal',
        last_name='User'
    )
    response = client.post(reverse('login'), data={'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'})

    assert response.status_code == 302
    return user_client
```

Comment: You shouldn't import User directly. In your application code you should use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and for your test code the pytest-django plugin provides the handy django_user_model fixture. Then user = User.objects.create_user becomes django_user_model.objects.create_user(...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/tree/53373573f905ec5e0ec5786f49efdcdca5ae41fd) and [pytest-factoryboy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-factoryboy) for [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) in Django. *You can also use them for [the custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) with [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) or [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser).

For example, create `UserFactory` class as shown below in `tests/factories.py`:

```py
# "tests/factories.py"

import factory

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = "John"
```

Then, register `UserFactory` class in `tests/conftest.py` as shown below. *You can use the registered `UserFactory` class as `user_factory` as a test's argument:

```py
# "tests/conftest.py"

import pytest

from pytest_factoryboy import register
from tests.factories import UserFactory

register(UserFactory) # You can use "user_factory" as a test's argument
```

Lastly, use `user_factory` as the argument for `test_get_username()` as shown below. *[build()](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Factory.build) doesn't use database while [create()](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Factory.create) uses database:

```py
# "tests/test_ex1.py"

def test_get_username(user_factory):
    user = user_factory.build()
    assert user.get_username() == "John"
```

```py
# "tests/test_ex1.py"

def test_get_username(db, user_factory):
    user = user_factory.create()
    assert user.get_username() == "John"
```